# Antenna network design, 868 MHz Rainsun antenna

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-antenna, lora

I want to add LoRa support to a PCB design of mine, and because I'm fabricating at JLCPCB, I am considering the following components (since they are well stocked):

- [DL-RFM95-868M](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Dreamlnk-DL_RFM95868M/C2844472) LoRa module
- [AN1603-868](https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/Rainsun_MicrowaveTech-AN1603868/C115720) SMD antenna

What I fail to find out is how to connect the antenna. Datasheets for other SMD antennas that I've found include suggested matching network designs; the one above doesn't.

Is there some generic way of doing it? How does one go about deciding on a network/schematic/PCB design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your pcb is is large enough and well placed, you might not need a matching circuit, but it is considered as good practice to include one.

I would advise you to put a pi-matching circuit and keep in mind that you will need to check for the matching circuit values with a VNA. Fortunately, there are now several cheap VNAs that will help you do the deed.